# LINQPad .net method description is not working after install Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linqpad

I got an LINQPad issue after I install Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

You may duplicate the Issue by follow steps.

1. A brand new laptop with only windows 7 Pro installed (without any .net framework installed).
2. Install ".NET Framework 4.6.1 (Offline Installer) (x86 and x64) - (Multiple Languages)"
3. Install ".NET Framework 4.6.1 Developer Pack and Language Packs (x86 and x64) - (English)"
4. Goes to .Net Framework 4.6.1 folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1"
5. Sort files by files type
6. Select all XML files(these XML files are LINQPad used for code intellisense reference) for 4.6.1 total is 126 files
7. Right click mouse then select "Copy"
8. Back to Parent folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework"
9. Create a new folder named "v4.0"
10. Goes into new created folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0"
11. "Paste" all Selected XML file Copy to this folder
12. Open LINQPad (latest version), the code Intellisense and .net method description is working properly.
13. Install Microsoft Office Pro 2016 and SQL Server Enterprise 2014.
14. Open LINQPad (latest version), the code Intellisense and .net method description is still working properly.
15. Install Visual Studio Enterprise 2017.
16. Open LINQPad (latest version), the code Intellisense is working fine. BUT THE.NET METHOD DESCRIPTION IS NOT WORKING. Please check below Screen Shot for the Issue.

[image]

In my old laptop which has Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Installed and LINQPad (latest version), then install Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, there is no above issue. So I think LINQPad may not access .Net framework and got properly .net method description if there is only Visual Studio 2017 enterprise installed.

Is there anybody could please help me out?

Comment: Did you reported a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are Original .Net Framework versions after installed Visual Studio 2017

[image]

To Make LinqPad Method Description Work Only Need Leave These Versions FrameWork

[image]